# What's the best way to setup Elementary for a "10ft interface"?

Tags: settings, display, user-interface

First, let me extend a kudos to the developers. Your distro has kept my interest MUCH longer than any other in over 15 years of use.

Second, I'm entertaining using this on my HTPC which runs Kodi, Steam, etc on my 55in tv, which I sit about 15-18 feet away from. What settings would you guys (the devs and/or the community) recommend for optimum view-ability while working within the desktop environment? I need to be able to interact with OS applications and their menus as well as the browser. Would implementing a "big picture" or "large display" mode benefit a lot of users?

Third, this is just a minor request I've made for every linux distro since its inception......there needs to be Solaar for Logitech Unifying Receiver available either by default or in the software center

Comment: I have the exact same setup you described and have made no special arrangements to enjoy this setup at 10 feet.